# Separated histograms in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm using the following code to produce three different histograms in the same graph. However, I was wondering, if it is possible to separate the three different histograms in three different graphs underneath each other with the same scaling on the x-axis for all three graphs. As an alternative I thought about turning the three histograms into densities and still have them in the same graph.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 2, sd = 0.2),
                 y = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 2),
                 z = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 2))



ggplot(melt(df), aes(value, fill = variable)) + geom_histogram(position = "dodge")+ scale_fill_manual(values = c('red','black','green'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid`. These functions allow to define the variable for which to separate the plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
gg <- melt(df)
ggplot(gg) + geom_bar(aes(x=value,fill=variable)) + facet_grid(variable~., scale.)
```

The function melt(...) transforms your data from "wide" format (values in different columns) to "long" format (valuesin one column, with an extra column indicating which value goes with which variable. This is a preferred format for ggplot. Then facet_grid(...) puts the different variables (x,y,z) into different graphs (or panels).
[image]

Use this for densities:

```
ggplot(gg) + 
  stat_density(aes(x=value, color=variable),geom="line",position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: You can also use frequency polygons to display the same information as the the histograms.  See [geom_freqpoly](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_freqpoly.html)